# Get file size from Google for Google Doc

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have to implement the download process for files stored/created on Google Drive.
The progress bar with percentage should be shown during download process.

So, for all previously uploaded files, I have property

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.getFileSize()
```

For native Google Drive docs, there is no such property. Actually there were some previous questions about it:

[Retrieve a "Google doc" created file size with the google drive api for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964278/retrieve-a-google-doc-created-file-size-with-the-google-drive-api-for-ios)

[Get size of file created on Google drive using Google drive api in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065308/get-size-of-file-created-on-google-drive-using-google-drive-api-in-android)

but there is no answer as well.

Headers

```
HttpResponse.getHeaders().getContentRange()
```

and

```
HttpResponse.getHeaders().getContentLength()
```

are nullable even if I try perform downloading with range header

```
Range : bytes=0-10
```

I totally stuck in it and do appreciate any help.

Comment: The answers to the linked questions are still accurate.

Comment: too bad :(.  so,  as I got there is no way to handle it