# Get size of files using Google drive API

Tags: java, google-drive-api, filesize

I am trying to list files from google drive along with their sizes for my app & below is the how i tried getting the size

```
File file = service.files().get(file.getId()).setFields("size").execute();
file.getSize()
```

I came to know that the size obtained from this call is not right as google drive only populates file size for files apart from google docs, sheet [Get size of file created on Google drive using Google drive api in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065308/get-size-of-file-created-on-google-drive-using-google-drive-api-in-android)

Also I tried determining file's size by making http GET to 
webContentLink & checking the Content-Length header like below

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        String url = "https://docs.google.com/a/document/d/1Gu7Q2Av2ZokZZyLjqBJHG7idE1dr35VE6rTuSii36_M/edit?usp=drivesdk";
        try {
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            conn.getInputStream();
            System.out.println(conn.getContentLength());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
```

But in this case , the file size is not correct as it comes out be very large

Is there any way I can determine the file size ?

Comment: Is there any google drive API which returns how much space has been used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem. For files uploaded to google drive, file size can be determined with file.getSize() call. For Google apps files such as doc, spreadsheet etc file.getSize() will return null as they don't consumer any space in drive. So as a hacky way, I am exporting as a pdf & determining the size. Below is the code for that

```
try {
            Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                        .setApplicationName("xyz")
                        .build();
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            service.files().export(fileId, "application/pdf")
                .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
            int fileSize = outputStream.toByteArray().length;
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
```

Comment: I'm curious, what is the significance of the size of a PDF export of the file?

Comment: I needed to display the file's size in the listing of google drive files so exporting it as pdf & displaying the size is what I settled for

Comment: Hmm OK, as long as you understand that it is not THE size, but rather is one of many sizes depending on export format.